What is the stance of Islam on discussing philosophies, beliefs, ideas, and practices of other religions or belief systems?
What are the rules or guidelines on how a Muslim should engage with others who would like to discuss philosophies, beliefs, ideas, and practices of other religions or belief systems?

Are Muslims allowed to discuss / engage in the ideas to some degree? Or is it shunned.
How does Islam incorporate ideas outside the main canon / system? (Generally speaking)
Are certain topics to be never discussed?

This would help me ask better questions to the Muslim community in general, but also would serve as a gauge as to how to interact. Basically, what is acceptable conversation topics in the end.

Lance hope you're doing well, and regarding your question that is it allowed in islam and the answer is yes indeed it is because we can see this from the time of Prophet SAW itself when he ordered Zayd Ibn Thabit(R) to keep firm knowledge about Judaism's traditional law and judge their social affairs upon their book and law so yes it is, and even in islamic history the big giants like Ibn Taymiyyah Al Razi Ibn Al-Qayyim Ibn Kathir and many other scholars do have these comparative study base knowledge and in Islamic Golden Age we can found numerous examples upon these dialogues which literally shows that it was the study criteria of every islamic institution at that time so yeah it is allowed to understand the cores of other beliefs and philosophies and then have a intellectual and academic discussion upon it but before that one should have to deep dive upon islamic realm of understanding with truthful aspect from muslim's view then based upon that we have to go away in that and judge the things based on Qur'an and sunnah because muslims believe that their book and messenger's law is most updated and final revealation from the almighty Allah.
